# Adding Box2d to Cocos3d

Tags: box2d, cocos3d

I want to include Box2d into a Cocos3d project (yes, I know it's a 2d physics engine), but I can't get it to work. Xcode does not find the box2d h-files. I've tried to setup the search paths, but it has no effect. Any suggestions? For instance it can't find Box2D/Collision/b2BroadPhase.h.

I did as follows:

1. copied the Box2d folder from a working cocos2d project, and put it
   in the libs folder in my Cocos3d project.
2. Added the files to the cocos3d project with the following selections:

   - copy into dest folder UNCHECKED
   - create groups for any added folders (i.e. not create folder references)
   - add to target was checked
3. after this I've added 'libs' in 'User header search paths' and 'Header search paths' for the whole project, and it seems to get inherited down to the target specific settings. 'Always search user paths' is checked.

I've found lots of questions regarding this, and I've tried many other solutions. This is my latest try. Is it something fishy with this??

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I did only state 'libs' as header search paths. The project now builds when I've stated 'projectName/libs' as search paths.

It's strange because I have tried to state absolute search paths, but I did not get that to work. I think I spelled it correctly.

Hope this can help somebody!